# How to add a schema location with StAX

Tags: java, xml, stax

I am using StAX and I want to add a schema location to my xml file. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `XMLStreamWriter`, you can just use `writeNamespace()` and `writeAttribute()` (or just `writeAttribute()`).

```
XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
xmlStreamWriter.writeStartDocument();
xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("YourRootElement");
xmlStreamWriter.writeNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
        "path_to_your.xsd");
xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlStreamWriter.flush();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<YourRootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="path_to_your.xsd"></YourRootElement>
```

For `XMLEventWriter`, you should be able to do it by `add()`ing a `createAttribute()`.

Regards,
Max

Comment: Hi Max, I already expected this solution. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This worked for me, but XML my XML didn't fully validate. To fix my validation problems, I needed to specify a newer schema instance as: `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.